# Closed Subgroup is Open in a certain Topological Group

Tags: general-topology, commutative-algebra, topological-groups

In any topological group it is easy to show open subgroups are closed.

Prove that the converse holds in the following situation:

Let G be an abelian group, and let $$G=G_0 \supset G_1 \supset G_2\supset \dots$$
be a chain of subgroups. We turn $G$ into a topological group by defining the following topology: $U \subset G$ is open if and only if for every $x \in U$ there is some $n \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $x+G_n \subset U$.

I want to show that every closed subgroup of $G$ is open.

Possible useful facts:

- The open subsets of $G$ are precisely unions of cosets of the $G_i$'s.
- A subgroup $K \subset G$ is open if and only if there is some $n \in \mathbb{N}$ with $G_n \subset K$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is false.

Consider $G=\mathbb{Z}$, with $G_n=p^n\mathbb{Z}$. Then $\{0\}$ is a closed subgroup which is not open.